# What could change the exe file

Tags: windows-7, windows

When I try to run *.exe on 64bit Windows7  I get the message (originally in russian)

```
*.exe is not Win32 application
```

I see that the date of change is recent on this exe file. Recently someone connected to this PC via teamviewer to fill some data inside this application. He says he didn't change exe itself(only run it and then made some changes inside the application itself and I partially monitored this process). What could change the exe file? Could it be some sort of virus?

Comment: It is more likely to be a mistake than intentional.  What is the .exe?

Comment: @Paul it's some program for managing restaurants, I mean how could he change exe itself by mistake?

Comment: He didn't necessarily - it could have been a separate event.  It is hard to be sure.  Can you open the .exe in notepad and it might shed some light on what happened.  If it isn't an .exe any more, it might be a text file.

Answer (score -1):

When you launch an executable file, Windows displays a message like:

```
Application name is not a valid Win32 application
```

.exe is a file execution extension. There are different file formats for different systems that are identifiable with the help of different alphabets that accompany them.

- File download
- IDE Controller badly configured
- Support CD / DVD unreadable
- File system corrupted
- File unregistered
- Virus / spyware

### Downloaded file

If the application in question was uploaded to the Internet, it is possible that it was corrupted during the download. In this case, just download the file again.

### IDE controller badly configured

- Right click on My Computer and select "Properties".
- In System Properties, select the Hardware tab then Device Manager.
- Double-click the IDE ATA / ATAPI controllers.
- Double-click on Primary IDE Channel and Secondary IDE channel.
- In the tab "Advanced Settings", under Device 0, ensure the command is set to DMA if available and not PIO only.

### CD / DVD is unreadable

If the error is caused by a defective media, follow the steps below:

- Try to read the CD / DVD in another drive
- Clean with a soft cloth and water (no soap)
- Attempt to retrieve the data with software such as Win ISO (free version), which will retrieve the damaged file

### File system corrupt

To check the integrity of protected system files, run the following command:

```
sfc/scannow
```

### File unregistered

If the error occurs at the opening of files, click Start / Run, then enter and confirm the following command:

```
regsvr32 / i SHELL32.DLL
```

Answer (score -1):

```
==>*.exe
'*.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

==>
```

As per [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) (*Naming Conventions* section:

> The following fundamental rules enable applications to create and
>   process valid names for files and directories, regardless of the file
>   system:
>
> ...
>
> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including
>   Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set
>   (128–255), except for the following:
>
> - The following reserved characters:
>
>   - `<` (less than)
>   - `>` (greater than)
>   - `:` (colon)
>   - `"` (double quote)
>   - `/` (forward slash)
>   - `\` (backslash)
>   - `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
>   - `?` (question mark)
>   - `*` (asterisk)
>   - Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the *ASCII* `NUL` character.
>   - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from `1` through `31`, except for alternate data streams where these characters
>       are allowed. For more information about file streams, see [File
>       Streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404(v=vs.85).aspx).
>   - Any other character that the target file system does not allow.
>
> ...